# Is it possible to transform my table into a different format using SQLlite?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to transform a table into a different format in this image.

Image :

[image]

Attached below are the data. I have a table on my database whose column headers are currently defined as col_0 ... col_7.

```
+----------+------------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
|  col_0   |      col_1       |    col_2    |    col_3     |    col_4    |    col_5     |    col_6    |    col_7     |
+----------+------------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
|          |                  | Spoon       |              | Fork        |              | Knife       |              |
| Location | Market Postcode  | Trade Price | Retail Price | Trade Price | Retail Price | Trade Price | Retail Price |
| Market A | AAA111           | 0.5         | 1            | 0.6         | 1.1          | 0.55        | NA           |
| Market B | BBB111           | 0.7         | 2            | 0.8         | 1.5          | NA          | NA           |
+----------+------------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I want that to be transformed in a way that I can see the trade and retail prices of each product for markets A and B.

```
+----------+------------------+---------+-------------+--------------+
|  col_0   |      col_1       |  col_2  |    col_3    |    col_4     |
+----------+------------------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| Location | Market Post Code | Product | Trade Price | Retail Price |
| Market A | AAA111           | Spoon   | 0.5         | 1            |
| Market A | AAA111           | Fork    | 0.6         | 1.1          |
| Market A | AAA111           | Knife   | 0.55        | NA           |
| Market B | BBB111           | Spoon   | 0.7         | 2            |
| Market B | BBB111           | Fork    | 0.8         | 1.5          |
| Market B | BBB111           | Knife   | NA          | NA           |
+----------+------------------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

I am very new to SQL and SQL lite and it would be nice if someone could assist me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Please include everything required to understand your problem in the question itself, rather than in links.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is not a complete question, because all of the critical information is contained in an external link, which might break over time.  Please finish your question by including the exact table definition and sample data as _text_, directly in your question.

Comment: Do you have a row:`null,Spoon,null,null,Fork,null,Knife,null`? And another row: `Location,Market Postcode,Trade Price,Retail Price,Trade Price,Retail Price,Trade Price,Retail Price`?

Comment: @forpas -  no I don't. Why did you ask?

Comment: Because these rows exist in the sample data you posted.

Comment: @forpas - I have null, null, Spoon, null, Fork, null, Knife, null and Location,Market Postcode,Trade Price,Retail Price,Trade Price,Retail Price,Trade Price,Retail Price

Comment: Did someone do a literal row-by-row import of a spreadsheet into a database table or something? That looks nasty. I'd do the conversion in a perl script or whatever instead of trying to do it purely in sqlite... Are answers like that acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's awkward, the following is an example :-

```
-- Create the original data
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS original;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS original (COL_0 TEXT, COL_1 TEXT, COL_2 TEXT, COL_3 TEXT, COL_4 TEXT, COL_5 TEXT, COL_6 TEXT, COL_7 TEXT);
INSERT INTO original VALUES
    (null,null,'Spoon','','Fork','','Knife',''),
    ('Location','Market Postocde','Trade Price','Retail Price','Trade Price','Retail Price','Trade Price','Reatail Price'),
    ('Market A','AAA111',0.5,1,0.6,1.1,0.55,'NA'),
    ('Market B','BBB111',0.7,2,0.8,1.5,'NA','NA')
;
SELECT * FROM original;

-- Prepare to create the transformed
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS transformed;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transformed (COL_0 TEXT, COL_1 TEXT, COL_2 TEXT, COL_3 TEXT, COL_4 TEXT);


WITH 
    item1 AS (SELECT COL_2 FROM original WHERE (length(COL_0) < 1 AND LENGTH(COL_1) < 1) OR (COL_0 IS NULL AND COL_1 IS NULL) ),
    item2 AS (SELECT COL_4 FROM original WHERE (length(COL_0) < 1 AND LENGTH(COL_1) < 1) OR (COL_0 IS NULL AND COL_1 IS NULL)),
    item3 AS (SELECT COL_6 FROM original WHERE (length(COL_0) < 1 AND LENGTH(COL_1) < 1) OR (COL_0 IS NULL AND COL_1 IS NULL)),

    full1 AS (SELECT COL_0, COL_1,(SELECT * FROM item1),COL_2,COl_3 FROM original WHERE length(COL_1) = 6),
    full2 AS (SELECT COL_0, COL_1,(SELECT * FROM item2),COL_4,COL_5 FROM original WHERE length(COL_1) = 6),
    full3 AS (SELECT COL_0, COL_1,(SELECT * FROM item3),COL_6,COL_7 FROM original WHERE length(COL_1) = 6),

    reformed AS (SELECT * FROM full1 UNION SELECT * FROM full2 UNION SELECT * FROM full3)

    INSERT INTO transformed SELECT * FROM reformed
;

SELECT * FROM transformed;
```

## Explanation

### Stage 1 - Create the Original Data

As per the comments the original data is created, the result of the select being :-

[image]

The above has also been run using :-

[image]

- i.e. col_0 and COL_1 can be either blank or null when the row contains two items.

### Stage 2 - Preparation

The next phase creates a table called transformed in which to receive the transformed data (i.e. a table with 5 columns).

### Stage 3 - The Transformation

This creates 2 sets of 3 Common Table Expression (i.e. there are 3 items) and a final CTE (reformed) that merges the 2nd set of CTE's, which is then passed to an INSERT into the prepared result table, named **transformed**.

The first set, just the specific items are generated by processing the original table and only selecting the column where the item will be found, i.e. rows where COl_0 and COL_1 are an empty string or are null.

The second set gets the columns with the data respective to the item AND the item from the respective item? CTE. The criteria for inclusion is that that market code is 6 characters in length.

The reformed CTE merges the three CTE's from the second set into a single CTE.

Lastly the reformed CTE is used to load the transformed table.

It has been assumed that the headings are not required as this would typically not be stored as actual data.

The result being :-

[image]